# Minimum number of query to find Largest sum of a contiguous subarray

Tags: algorithms

Consider [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142787/largest-sum-of-a-contiguous-subarray-using-queries-of-the-same-form), the problem is
given an array $A[1..n]$. We don't have direct access to $A$, but we can query what is the sum of $A[i..j]$ for every interval $i..j$. We would like to find the maximum of $A[i..j]$ over all intervals $i..j$.

**That answer describe an algorithm that solve the problem with  at most $O(n)$ query, but
the question is, what is the lower bound of number queries we need to find largest continuous sub array? Can we claim that $\Omega(n)$ queries is necessary?**

Comment: Imagine all elements to have value zero.

Comment: @greybeard 
How this help us? Could you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

At least $n$ queries are needed in the worst case.$^*$ Consider an algorithm which receives the answer $0$ on any query. After $n-1$ queries, it learns that $\langle v^{(1)},A \rangle = \cdots = \langle v^{(n-1)},A \rangle = 0$, where $v^{(i)}$ is the vector corresponding to the $i$'th query. We can find a non-zero vector $u$ which is orthogonal to all of $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$. Thus we could have $A = u$ or $A = -u$. We claim that an answer which is valid for $A = u$ is not valid for $A = -u$. Since the algorithm cannot tell these two cases apart, it cannot guarantee outputting a valid solution.

To prove the claim, suppose without loss of generality that $u$ contains a positive entry. Therefore any optimal solution $I$ for $u$ satisfies $\sum_{i \in I} u_i > 0$. In contrast, $\sum_{i \in I} (-u)_i < 0$. We now distinguish between two cases:

- Case 1: Some entry of $u$ is non-positive. In this case, the optimal solution $J$ for $-u$ satisfies $\sum_{j \in J} (-u)_j \geq 0$, and so we are done.
- Case 2: All entries of $u$ are positive. **If $n > 1$,** this means that the unique optimal solution for $u$ is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, whereas all optimal solutions of $u$ are either singletons or the empty interval, if we allow it. **If $n = 1$,** then this argument breaks unless we allow the empty interval as a solution. Indeed, if $n = 1$ and we don't allow the empty interval, then no queries are needed. This is the reason for the asterisk above.

---

A similar approach shows that $n$ queries are needed *always*. Suppose that after $n-1$ queries, the algorithm learns that $\langle v^{(i)}, A \rangle = c_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$. The space of solutions to these equations includes a line $\alpha u + w$ (here $\alpha$ is the parameter), where $u \neq 0$. For large positive $\alpha$, any optimal solution for $\alpha u + w$ is also an optimal solution for $u$. This is since if $\sum_{i \in I} u_i > \sum_{j \in J} u_j$ then
$$
\sum_{i \in I} (\alpha u_i + w_i) - \sum_{j \in J} (\alpha u_j + w_j) =
\alpha \left(\sum_{i \in I} u_i - \sum_{j \in J} u_j\right) + \left(\sum_{i \in I} w_i - \sum_{j \in J} w_j\right),
$$
which is positive for large enough $\alpha$, say $\alpha > \alpha_{I,J}$. The claim follows since there are only finitely many pairs $I,J$.
Similarly, for large negative $\alpha$, any optimal solution for $\alpha u + w$ is also an optimal solution for $-u$. Above we have shown that an optimal solution for $u$ cannot be an optimal solution for $-u$ (unless $n = 1$ and we do not allow the empty interval).

Comment: $ v^i=A[1..i]$? Or $v^i=A[i]$?

Comment: No. It is the vector which represents the $i$'th query. It has the same length as $A$, and its entries are $0$ and $1$. Furthermore, the $1$s are consecutive.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain more about "We can find a non-zero vector u which is orthogonal to all of $v_1,…,v_{n−1}$."?

Comment: That's linear algebra.

Comment: Ooh:) I wasn't passed linear algebra course:).

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you perform less than $n$ queries, so obtain less than $n$ sums. The corresponding system of equations so obtained is indeterminate, leaving room for degrees of freedom to move the maximum at different places.

E.g. for $n=3$, assume we query $a+b=5$ and $b+c=4$. Then $a=5-b$, $c=4-b$ and $a+b+c=9-b$, with $b$ free. So with large positive $b$, the optimal sequence would be $b$ alone, and with large negative $b$, it would be $a+b+c$.

Comment: Upvoted. While Yuval's answer is great, this answer is easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

For every 1 ≤ j < n: We must make a query ending in $A_j$ otherwise we cannot determine the largest sum.

Reason: Assume we determined all subarray sums for all subarrays not ending in $A_j$. If we increase $A_j$ by a huge amount and decrease $A_{j+1}$ by the same amount, then the largest subarray sum is for a subarray ending in $A_j$. But if we decrease $A_j$ by a huge amount and increases $A_{j+1}$ by the same amount, the largest subarray sum is NOT for a subarray ending in $A_j$. Both actions leave all the subarray sums that we queried unchanged, so we cannot determine the largest subarray sum without an interval ending at $A_j$.

We also need an interval containing $A_n$, because $A_n$_ could be very large or very small so it cannot be ignored. So n intervals are needed. And the intervals A[1..1], A[1..2], ..., A[1..n] are sufficient because we can calculate all subarray sums from these. Or we could take A[1..1], A[2..2], ..., A[n..n].

Comment: Suppose that $n = 3$ and you query $A[1],A[3],A[1]+A[2]+A[3]$.

Comment: At the line "Reason: Assume we determined all subarray sums for all subarrays not ending in $A_j$", all sub arrays ony contains subarrays from $1$ to $j-1$? or contains sub arrays from $1$ to $j-1$ and $j+1$ to $n$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Is there a simple argument that show us the lower bound of number of times that we make queries is $\omega(\log n)$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "simple".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If it's complex I have no problem. Also I prefer to give me some hint not full solution.

Comment: I try to find a problem that show us if we solve above problem with less than $o(\log n)$ queries then we can solve a problem in less that its lower bound. Like sorting that has $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Also I think maybe there is an instance that need $\Omega(n)$ queries. But I can't find such an instance.